# TypeScript: Declaring an array of extended types

Tags: typescript, class, types

I am facing this situation now where i dynamically import every model of my application into an array. Each model has shared properties from Model and its own, however, I don't know how to type my "model extended" array.

> EDIT:  I am using `sequelize` for Models in my server. I need my `User` model that extends from `Model` and is dynamically imported into my App to have its properties (let's say email and password).
>   However, if this is a Model array I can't access the properties I am talking about in the User model.

```
class Vehicle {
  public a = 1;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  public b = 2;
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
  public c = 3;
}

const vehicleArray: any extends Vehicle[] = [Car, Bike];

vehicleArray.map((vehicle) => {
  console.log(vehicle.a) // :)
  console.log(vehicle.b) // :(
  console.log(vehicle.c) // :(
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#)

Comment: Since `Bike` and `Car` are both vehicles why not just do `const vehicleArray: Vehicle[]` ?

Comment: As @apokryfos suggests, and then narrow using `instanceof`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeBYAUNaADgK4BGIq0Y0AvNAIwDcuAvrrqJDAMJgBO08AB4AXeADsAJjAQo0mXPmJkKJGtABMTHKxztwUaACFkAa3RDRk6UlQh02PIVLlg0V7QDMWnewD2YiGFoADcbNABBXl4wAE8ALjgwuwBtAF01ZLF4AHdoHl4ACgBKABpoLNzjM2LUrVxQ2TtI6JiAOgBbMAICgobbeCKaAD55R3xgfwhfO1aQXwBzXqT4VrBBgHp16DiihXxoZAAzaCXG9GQA4TAxYHhfY-zBh32Xt0nplbnFvrRWkg2tjs9vgdC8jicfnYDpdrrd7kZTANRq99hMAh9ZgtTv1WsAAdtdmNoDpmEUGEA

Comment: Let's say I want to use property `b` and `c` that are only in `Car` and `Bike`. Is there any way to use them without abstractly declaring these properties in `Vehicle`?

Comment: @Zeswen only by checking for derived type instances with `instnceof`  as in my code

Comment: Got it, not entirely happy about it but I guess thats it! Thank you both!

Comment: What about [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeBYAUNaADgK4BGIq0Y0AvNAIwDcuAvrrqJDAMJgBO08AB4AXeADsAJjAQo0mXPmJkKJGtABMTHKxztwUaACFkAa3RDRk6UlQh02PIVLlg0V7QDMWnewD2YiGFoADcbNABBXl4wAE81AG0xeAB3aB5eABpoJNTjMwBdLQB6IuhkADNoGN8iaEQwUOhhX2gAc2RG5CCqYRiCeCz2zqCAA0jomIAedOgAHyNTeAA+EbYcUNk7cdiAOgBbMAIACiON23gAShol+UdgfwhfOx2QX1bTsOewK5LoAC4LgoypUjgAiEigspiEKfS63fD4e4BJ7wF5vD6bVEkC5afDMAQgCD2IGIh4otHvM5oHbAHFAnTMHFAA)?  Does that work for you?